# How to use ViewPager OnTouchListener with ImageView inside it which also has OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have a ViewPager that have 4 pages, the pages will keep sliding using runable and handler....each page contains an ImageView, the ImageView onClickListener event is set in the Adapter

the ViewPager has OnTouchListener event set while initialization

I'm setting the ViewPager OnTouchListener event to stop sliding when the user touches the viewpager and continue sliding when user release his finger

here is how i set ViewPager OnTouchListener event:

```
    BandsViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    stopSliding = true;
                    bandsHandler.removeCallbacks(animateBandsViewPager);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // calls when touch release on ViewPager
                    if (bands != null && bands.size() != 0) {
                        stopSliding = false;
                        bandsRunnable(bands.size());
                        bandsHandler.postDelayed(animateBandsViewPager, ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);
                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // calls when ViewPager touch
                    if (bandsHandler != null && stopSliding == false) {
                        stopSliding = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and Here is how I set ImageView OnClickListener inside the ViewPager adapter class:

```
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(ClickActionType){
                case BAND_CLICK_ACTION_BRAND:
                    Categories_Fragment categoriesFrag= new Categories_Fragment();
                    Bundle categoriesArgs = new Bundle();
                    categoriesArgs.putInt("BrandId", ClickActionTypeId);
                    categoriesArgs.putInt("TabId", TabId);
                    if (UI.getAppLanguage() == 0)
                        categoriesArgs.putString("BrandName", TitleAr);
                    else
                        categoriesArgs.putString("BrandName", TitleEn);
                    categoriesFrag.setArguments(categoriesArgs);
                    FManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.main_content, categoriesFrag, Categories_Fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                            .addToBackStack(Categories_Fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                            .commit();
                    break;

                case BAND_CLICK_ACTION_ITEM:
                    Item_Details_Fragment itemDetailsFrag= new Item_Details_Fragment();
                    Bundle itemDetailsArgs = new Bundle();
                    itemDetailsArgs.putInt("ItemId", ClickActionTypeId);
                    itemDetailsFrag.setArguments(itemDetailsArgs);
                    FManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.main_content, itemDetailsFrag, Item_Details_Fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                            .addToBackStack(Item_Details_Fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                            .commit();
                    break;
                case BAND_CLICK_ACTION_CATEGORY:
                    Items_Fragment itemsFrag= new Items_Fragment();
                    Bundle itemsArgs = new Bundle();
                    itemsArgs.putInt("CategoryId", ClickActionTypeId);
                    if (UI.getAppLanguage() == 0)
                        itemsArgs.putString("CategoryName", TitleAr);
                    else
                        itemsArgs.putString("CategoryName", TitleEn);
                    itemsArgs.putInt("BrandId", 0);
                    itemsArgs.putInt("TabId", TabId);
                    itemsFrag.setArguments(itemsArgs);
                    FManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.main_content, itemsFrag, Items_Fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                            .addToBackStack(Items_Fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                            .commit();
                    break;
                default:
            }

        }
    });
```

If I remove the ImageView OnClickListener then the ViewPager will receive touch events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `ImageView` is stealing the `MotionEvent` callbacks from your `ViewPager` is because the `OnTouchListener.onTouch()` method of your `ViewPager` always returns `false`. This means it will not capture any new `MotionEvent` callbacks after another `View` (your `ImageView`) returns `true` in the `onTouchEvent()` method. Any `View` that is "clickable" returns `true` for any `MotionEvent`, and setting an `OnClickListener` for a `View` makes it clickable.

Now the immediate reaction might be to make the `OnTouchListener.onTouch()` method return `true` for some or all `case` statements. But this would either make the `ViewPager` intercept *all* `MotionEvent` callbacks, or not give you the functionality that you want.

The correct implementation would be to subclass `ViewPager` and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` methods. The key is not to return `true` in the case of `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` in `onTouchEvent`, as this will delegate every gesture to the `ViewPager`. Instead you should *intercept* the `MotionEvent` callbacks in the case of `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` after a ["slop"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html) threshold has been exceeded. This will send all successive `MotionEvent` callbacks to the `ViewPager.onTouchEvent()` method, instead of any child views.

The Android documentation includes best practices on [managing touch events](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html). I also highly recommend watching [Mastering the Android Touch System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI) if you want to have a better understanding of how the Android framework handles touch events.